# When I summon a cat familiar, why does it matter if it is a fey or fiend or celestial?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

It says in the summoning spell that when you summon an animal it is a fey fiend or celestial (your choice). What does this do? Do they get any abilities or buffs from these like types?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the tour (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the help (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) center for more guidance.

Comment: The related question asked by OP: [Can my familiar turn me invisible?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153693/can-my-familiar-turn-me-invisible)

Comment: You should still clarify whether you're talking about the *find familiar* spell, or a familiar gained some other way. Given your other question, I'm assuming it is indeed the *find familiar* spell, and that you know it as a wizard, but it'd be good to have confirmation.

Comment: I edited out what I think is actually [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153693/52137) (Assuming "emperor" is a mistranslation for "imp"). Feel free to call me on (and edit it back in) if that is still relevant to this question.

Answer (score 19):

## It only matters due to other game features

Firstly there are no innate bonuses from creature type. There are however some features which care about creature type:

- Firstly, the familiar is not a beast anymore, so spells like [*beast bond*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beast-bond) do not affect it.
- A few (cleric) spells care about creature type and about celestial, fey, and fiend in particular. [*Hallow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow) prevents any of them from entering the area. [*Temple of the Gods*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/temple-of-the-gods) and [*Forbiddance*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forbiddance) prevent a caster's choice of those creatures (+Elementals and undead) from entering the area (or deals 5d10 damage per turn without a save, which is fairly equivalent).
- If you are a Circle of the Shepherd druid a few of your features care about beasts or fey you've created or summoned, giving it buffs like additional hit points. Thus choosing the specific type is relevant if you are such a druid with access to [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar). ([See this Q&A of mine for more details.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152569/52137))
- There are numerous other game features, like Ranger's [Favoured Enemy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#FavoredEnemy-294), that could hypothetically be relevant, but which are even less likely to come up.

These are all fairly niche interactions, so you are pretty much free to choose whichever you like, or feel fit your character, irrespective of mechanical benefits.

Comment: This might be improved a bit with some fluff explanation. Having a Fiendish familiar might you not be friends with the local Paladin crew anymore if they find out, for example.

Comment: @Erik as that would be extremely setting dependent I don't think going on that tangent would be an improvement

Comment: @Cubic Paladins have the most strange and inconsistent limits on creature types. Paladin Divine Sense will find celestial or fiend but not fey. Turn the Unholy and Holy Nimbus affects fiends. Turn the Faithless helps against fiends or fey. And most of those are capable of friendly fire too. So fiendish familiar is not a good choice in party with paladin irrespective of setting.

Comment: Another thing that impacts this would be the *magic circle* spell if you wanted to include that